# Duplicated JSON array validation

Tags: javascript

There is `names` array includes the name `object`.

I tried to use this way, but I think there is a better way to solve.

```js
const names = [
  {name: 'aa'},
  {name: 'bb'},
  {name: 'cc'},
  {name: 'aa'}
]

const isDuplicatedName = names.some(({name}, index, names) => {
  return names.filter((row, idx) => row.name === name && index !== idx).length;
})

console.log(isDuplicatedName)
```

Is there another better way to solve this using `some` and `filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of [sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as they can only contain unique values, make a new set from the vales and check the [.size()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size) of the set against the original array length.

Little shorter, but would recommend sticking with something you understand that maintains readability.

```js
const names = [
  {name: 'aa'},
  {name: 'bb'},
  {name: 'cc'},
  {name: 'aa'}
]

const isDuplicatedName = new Set(names.map(a => a.name)).size !== names.length;


console.log(isDuplicatedName)
```

Comment: you can also use `new Set(names.map(a => a.name)).size`

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, edited in, thanks for pointing out! dont work with sets all to much

Answer (score 2):

On each iteration, check to see if the current name being iterated over is included in the set (and if so, break), then add the current name to that Set, for an overall complexity of `O(n)`:

```js
const names = [
  {name: 'aa'},
  {name: 'bb'},
  {name: 'cc'},
  {name: 'aa'}
];

const namesSet = new Set();

const isDuplicatedName = names.some(({name}) => {
  if (namesSet.has(name)) {
    return true;
  }
  namesSet.add(name);
  return false;
});

console.log(isDuplicatedName)
```

(in contrast, `.filter` inside `.some` has `O(n^2)` complexity)

Looking at your original code, for a general rule, if you ever see code like `arr.filter(callback).length;`, you can improve it by not constructing an unnecessary intermediate array by using `reduce` instead:

```
return names.filter((row, idx) => row.name === name && index !== idx).length;
```

can be changed to

```
return names.reduce((countSoFar, row, idx) => countSoFar + (row.name === name && index !== idx), 0);
```

(which would probably be more appropriate, but would still be more inefficient than the Set solution)

Comment: Tbh I like yours answer more than mine.

Answer (score 1):

if possible, you can `.map` the array so that you have only an array with names. Then you can use `.includes` to find any matches.

```js
const names = [
  {name: 'aa'},
  {name: 'bb'},
  {name: 'cc'},
  {name: 'aa'}
]

const isDuplicatedName = names.map(o => o.name).some((name, index, names) => names.includes(name))

console.log(isDuplicatedName)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work with only one loop:

```
    function checkIfArrayIsUnique(arr) {
    var map = {}, i, size;

    for (i = 0, size = arr.length; i < size; i++){
        if (map[arr[i]]){
            return false;
        }

        map[arr[i]] = true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` the data to a map of `key: name, value: count`. Then take the keys of the map via `Object.keys`  and check whether a single value is `> 1` via `some`. The complexity of this is O(n).

```js
const names = [{name:'aa'},{name:'bb'},{name:'cc'},{name:'aa'}]

function isDuplicatedName (arr) {
  let map = arr.reduce((a,c) => (a[c.name] = (a[c.name] || 0) + 1, a), {});
  return Object.keys(map).some(k => map[k] > 1);
}

console.log(isDuplicatedName(names))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also done it by plain JS

```
function checkDuplicate(array) {
    let obj = {};
    let isExist = false;
    for(name of array){
        console.log(name);
        if(obj[name.name]) {
            isExist = true;
            break;
        } else {
            obj[name.name] = name
        }
    }
    return isExist;
}
```

Or you can just check the difference between length it is the simplest solution I believe, you must try this, If it really helps you out

```
let newNames = Array.from(new Set(names));
console.log(newNames.length===names.length)
```

Comment: second one just only work for simple arrays not for array of objects